# How to ignore "git pull" errors when unstaged changes cannot be removed

Tags: git

When I run `git pull`, I get the following error:

```
Updating 745a0be..5b50b37
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    src/main/config/runtime/common/app/log4j2.json
    src/main/config/runtime/dev/app/application.properties
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting
```

All of the answers I have looked at so far have involved using `git stash`, `git checkout -- .` or `git reset --hard HEAD` to remove those files. However, in this case these unstaged changes are due to new-line normalization as a result of the repo's `.gitattributes` file:

```
* text=auto
```

Running `git stash`, `git checkout -- .` or `git reset --hard HEAD` all do nothing to clear any unstaged changes from my repo.

`git stash`:

```
$ git stash
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in src/main/config/runtime/common/app/log4j2.json.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in src/main/config/runtime/dev/app/application.properties.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
Saved working directory and index state WIP on master: 745a0be Merge pull request #37 in AS/openshift-example from json-validate to dmz
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 30 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   src/main/config/runtime/common/app/log4j2.json
    modified:   src/main/config/runtime/dev/app/application.properties

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

`git checkout -- .`:

```
$ git checkout -- .
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 30 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   src/main/config/runtime/common/app/log4j2.json
    modified:   src/main/config/runtime/dev/app/application.properties

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

`git reset --hard HEAD`:

```
$ git reset --hard HEAD
HEAD is now at 745a0be Merge pull request #37 in AS/openshift-example from json-validate to dmz
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 30 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   src/main/config/runtime/common/app/log4j2.json
    modified:   src/main/config/runtime/dev/app/application.properties

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

How do I tell `git pull` to just overwrite any local changes?

**Update:**

I have tried `git pull --force` and that gives the same error:

```
$ git pull --force
Updating 745a0be..5b50b37
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    src/main/config/runtime/common/app/log4j2.json
    src/main/config/runtime/dev/app/application.properties
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting
```

Comment: git pull --force

Comment: @NicolásAlarcónR. Same error.

Comment: Easy ¡¡¡ You execute : `git add .` and `git commit -m "Merge"` and `git merge`

Comment: Ah, yes but the the merge does't do a fast-forward and instead creates a merge commit too.

Comment: Which version of git? Also, what is your `core.autocrlf` configuration set to? `git config core.autocrlf` ? The solution here is not to try to coax pull or merge or stash or whatever to work with the modified files, but to figure out and fix why you get the files modified in the first place. Don't treat the symptom, treat the underlying problem.

Comment: I'd recommend *not* applying `* text=auto` to files that should or should not not have CR-LF in them explicitly, rather than automatically based on whether Git guesses that these are text files. It seems likely that these `.json` and `.properties` files are such files—some program(s) expect(s) them to have some particular line-ending so they are committed that way in the repository, and should not be fiddled-with by a program like Git that is ignorant of their intended use.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen `core.autocrlf` is not set. The newline setting is set in the `.gitattributes` file in the repo.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a "forced pull".  (There *is* a `--force`flag to `git fetch`, and `git pull` will pass `--force` to `git fetch`, but that's not useful for this case.)

Aside from fixing the actual problem, there is a way to work around this for now, by not using `git pull`.  Instead, run `git fetch` first, then `git reset --hard`:

```
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/master
```

(assuming you are on your `master`, which you are, and you don't want to keep the local changes you / your-Git made based on the `* text=auto` line, which you say you don't).  If whoever controls your `origin` repo has fixed the underlying problem here—whether that's to avoid treating `*.json` and `*.properties` as text, or to clean up the committed contents of these files, or both—you'll pick up the fix at the same time.  If not, you can ask them to fix it, or submit a fix to them, afterward.

Comment: As I stated in my original question, `git reset --hard` does not get rid of the unstaged changes.

Comment: Yes. It won't get rid of these unstaged changes, that are due to the actual underlying problem. However, after running `git fetch` first, it *will* reset you to the current commit. You'll have the latest files in your work-tree, with or without unstaged changes due to that underlying problem (namely that the line endings in the stored, permanent, committed files don't match the line endings called for by the configuration).

Comment: If the latest commit has those files corrected and/or the `.gitattributes` directives corrected, the unstaged changes issue should be gone. If not, it will continue to be there, but you can continue to work around them like this.